# HTC Explorer .tar ODIN

Tags: odin, htc-explorer

Not able to install the .tar file from http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads/P10 using ODIN. ODIN says the package is invalid. My mobile is HTC Explorer. Can someone let me know, whether ODIN can be used for other phones other than Samsung or not ? Also why invalid package error popping up on screen ?

thanks in advance

Comment: What you got from HTC Dev center is just source code in a tarball( namely compressed source code ). You can't flash that through fastboot or recovery let alone ODIN. As Matthew Read says ODIN is only for samsung devices.

Answer (score 1):

No, Odin is an internal Samsung tool.  <s>I assume you would use Fastboot or an HTC tool in this case.</s> Edit: I didn't pay enough attention to the webpage — as varunyellina says that's just source code, you can't flash it at all.

Comment: so you & @varunyellina mean to say that the .tar extension given from HTC shall be installable from the recovery section of my mobile directly just as .zip files which I had done earlier ?

Comment: @shobhan Please see my update.

Comment: all right. got it.